Snowflake Git Integration error when using repository files
I manged to follow and set up git integration
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/git/git-setting-up
I can also fetch from the Azure DevOps repo...
However, when I try to use files within the repo in any way

I get this error

 An error occurred while trying to download the file: {"error":{"message":"blockBlob download failed"}} 

Anybody know what's happening here?
